# Define hyphenated attribute with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm making a test app using jQuery mobile and Phonegap.
I have the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery Mobile: Theme Download</title>
    <script src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Longmont.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.css">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                       navigator.splashscreen.hide();
                       }, 500);
        }
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://localhost/api.php', {'id':3}, function(data) {
            var items = [];

            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                items.push('<div data-role="collapsible"><h1>' + val + '</h1></div>');
            });

            $('<div/>', {
                data-role: 'collapsible-set',
                html: items.join('')
            }).appendTo('#page');

        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to put the items array into a div with the `data-role` set to `collapsible-content`.
So, I edit the attribute when creating it (in `$('<div/>', {`). However, this attribute is hyphenated, and when I try this code in the simulator it displays a blank page.

What is the proper way to represent a hyphenated attribute in jQuery?

Comment: FYI, the problem has nothing to do with jQuery, but with JavaScript. The same way you cannot have `-` in a variable name, you cannot have it in a property name (as string it's fine of course).

Comment: I have added reference to my answer for future use, good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To define attribute with hyphen, check this answer by *Kevin B*
>   [Define hyphenated attribute with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911833/define-hyphenated-attribute-with-jquery/15911862#15911862)

---

> To enhance collapsible markup, follow the methods below after appending the items into body.

For collapsible ([reference](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/))

```
$('[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
```

For collapsible-set ([reference](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible-set/#method-refresh))

```
$('[data-role=collapsible-set]').collapsibleset('refresh');
```

Comment: Copy and pasting an answer to the same question from someone else? Even with the link, that's pretty borderline. I'd recommend to just link to it.

Answer (score 13):

object properties that contain `-` must be wrapped in quotes.

```
"data-role": value
```

The same goes for other operators and special characters such as quotes, `:`, `;`, spaces, etc.

Comment: Your answer was correct! Thank you, but then it left me with a problem that was solved by Omar.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `data` is not exactly analogous to `dataset`, nor should it be because that is not as widely supported as we'd like thanks to MS.  `data-role` is invalid syntax, but `dataRole` does not work either even if you'd expect it to.  You can either do:

```
"data-role": value
```

or

```
{data: {role: value}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/dK8ak/1/

Comment: I like the `{data: {role: value}}` syntax, it allows you to pass the value as is rather than converting it to a string just to convert it back to a number for example later. There is an important difference though, `{data: {role: value}}` won't actually create an attribute.